# Решения дизайна: картинки или стили

Tags: дизайн, вёрстка

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что выгоднее: использовать при вёрстке картинки или стили?
Поясню: например, кнопку "отправить" можно сделать 2 способами: нарисовав её в графическом редакторе или оформив input с помощью стилей. Что лучше с точки зрения трудоёмкости/красивости/оптимальности?

Сам заметил, что большинство сайтов используют вариант со стилями.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Стили более гибкие, потому что в процессе разработки/эксплуатации сайта, может возникнуть потребность поменять название кнопки, тень или цвет. В стилях это делается за секунды и нет нужны привлекать дизайнера, а вот с картинками всё наоборот. Также картинки занимают некоторый объём и, если их много, то их вес может повлиять на скорость загрузки страницы.

Comment: Принимаю этот ответ, так как он первый и соответствует вопросу) что ж, пойду учиться делать красивые вещи стилями) не подскажете каких-нибудь сайтов по этой теме?

Comment: посмотрите на twitter bootstrap :)

ну и классика жанра http://www.htmlbook.ru :)

Answer (score 0):

Смотря какие картинки. Если сумма картинок превышает 1 мб, я бы лучше использовал стили. Кстати с css3 - стало проще, можно градиент делать, что экономит как количеству обращение к серверу так и размер. Также чтобы оптимизировать можно картинки засунуть в base64 ( особенно мелкие картинки) - это сэкономит количеству подключение к серверу и повысит скорость. А вообще смотря по ситуации, но я думаю все-же через стили оптимизированные, через картинки практичнее. Объясняю, ведь CCS3 не все браузеры поддерживают нормально, в частотности ИЕ))). Если выбрать 1 из 2, я бы выбрал стили ;-)

Comment: А пусть пользователи ие не надеются вкусить красивостей веб сайтов:-)

Comment: Как это не печально, но еще весомый % людей пользуются этим творением... В основном, кто плохо пользуется ПК или кому все равно))). А да еще вариант - кто фанат этого творения =)

Comment: ну в последних версиях ИЕ уже не настолько плох как был... :) врядли много народу, который еще пользуется чемнить типа IE6 :)